# how to use two decimal points in mysql with case statements

Tags: mysql, sql, case

```
SELECT (CASE FI_Type
            WHEN 'Percentage' THEN FS_Price*FI_Ins_Amount/100
            ELSE FI_Ins_Amount
        END) AMOUNT,
             `FI_Ins_NO`,
             `FI_Type`,
             `FS_Registration_Fee`,
             `FS_Price`
FROM `fee_structure`
INNER JOIN `fee_installments` ON `fee_structure`.`FS_Code` = `fee_installments`.`FI_Stru_Code`
WHERE FS_Code='AL-ICT/1'
ORDER BY FI_Ins_NO ASC
```

`FI_Ins_Amount,FS_Price` table definitions is `decimal(10,2)`.but when return `FI_Ins_Amount` using this `CASE` statement also with calculations it shows me

`FI_Ins_Amount = 20000.00000000`  Instead of just `20000.00.`

Why tailing Zeros ?

Comment: nothing to do with case statements. you're doing math with the decimal values, and the results of that math will have more decimal places than you started out with.

Comment: So how i round up it ?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round ?

Comment: No! don't use round if you need decimal. Do a cast. Rounding results vary from server version to server version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FS_Price is decimal
FS_Price/1 is float
1 is integer
1/1 is float

select cast(1/1 as decimal(10,2)) -- > decimal
```

happens when you divide.

***Using round(float_value, 2) might yield unexpected results depending on server version**

```
select ROUND(25E-1),cast(25E-1 as decimal(10))
-- >2, 3
```

Expected result is round away from 0? Well, `Round`, does not agree in this case

for your case,

```
 CAST(CASE FI_Type
            WHEN 'Percentage' THEN FS_Price*FI_Ins_Amount/100
            ELSE FI_Ins_Amount
        END as DECIMAL(10,2)) as AMOUNT,
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') as DECIMAL(10,2)) as AMOUNT, `FI_Ins_NO`, `FI_Type`,' at line 4

Comment: remove the paranthesis

Comment: @samitha, use the proper function for the job. Cast, not round

Answer (score 0):

The math expression is creating the extra zeros, not the `CASE`. Try something like this if you only want two decimals, but note that *the front end is the best place for formatting*:

```
SELECT
   ROUND(CASE FI_Type
     WHEN 'Percentage' THEN FS_Price*FI_Ins_Amount/100
     ELSE FI_Ins_Amount END, 2) AMOUNT,
....
```